# Why does app crash when back from camera?

Tags: android

When the x button on the photo taking page it would crash. This is the error shown:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'java.lang.Object android.os.BaseBundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a
> null object reference.

i have tried using `finish()`; still would crash.

```
package sp.com;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class navigation_drawer extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int CAMERA_PERM_CODE = 101;
    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 102;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    ImageView imageView;
    Button camera;




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return  true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void  onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE){
            Bitmap image= (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        }else if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && data !=null){
                Uri selectedImage =data.getData();
                ImageView imageView=findViewById(R.id.displaypickedimage);
                imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }else{
            finish();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

        drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView=findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        actionBarDrawerToggle= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.menu_Open,R.string.menu_Close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        Log.i("MENU_DRAWER_TAG","Home item is clicked");
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        Intent home=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),navigation_drawer.class);
                        startActivity(home);
                        break;


                    case R.id.nav_login:
                        Log.i("MENU_DRAWER_TAG","Login item is clicked");
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        Intent login =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),staff_login.class);
                        startActivity(login);
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_feedback:
                        Log.i("MENU_DRAWER_TAG","Feedback item is clicked");
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        Intent feedback =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),feedback.class);
                        startActivity(feedback);
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_about:
                        Log.i("MENU_DRAWER_TAG","About item is clicked");
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        Intent about =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),about.class);
                        startActivity(about);
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        Button pick_image=findViewById(R.id.pick_image_gallery);
        pick_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent,3);

            }
        });

        imageView=findViewById(R.id.displaypickedimage);
        camera=findViewById(R.id.pick_image_camara);

        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                askCameraPermissions();

            }
        });


    }

    private void askCameraPermissions() {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},CAMERA_PERM_CODE);
        }else {
            openCamera();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode==CAMERA_PERM_CODE){
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                openCamera();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Camera Permission is Required to Use Camera",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        Intent camera=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(camera, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }



}
```

Comment: finish() is used to exit the activity

Comment: From your IDE, where does this error point to, could you add more error logs to the question?

Comment: It already has a stacktrace, just not well placed, there's a pending edit on this

Comment: the error is shows on Bitmap image= (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");